# Can we store npm package somewhere from we can download directly?

Tags: node.js, jenkins, openshift

I am using Jenkins and openshift 4.3. We Have AngularJS app which takes 1hr for build and deploy. Build time is increased due to `npm install`. Is there a way where we can store these modules and use in Jenkins build step instead of downloading each time? We want to reduce our build time. Can someone help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nexus](https://blog.sonatype.com/sonatype-nexus-installation-using-docker) as your private npm repository. Nexus will proxies everything i.e. all the required dependencies, from official npm registry that are required to build the project at your first build run.

It then stores it in the blobs which will serve as cache to your build packages for other consecutive build runs. In this way, you can reduce your build time.

You can refer this article for Sonatype Nexus on [Using Nexus 3 as your repository for NPM packages](https://blog.sonatype.com/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-2-npm-packages)